# Very poor formatting approved... again

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

[This edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5378374) in this question: [Can we use Restler on Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24925962/can-we-use-restler-on-google-app-engine)

I was going to edit this myself, but it was accepted in the meantime, with three accepts vs one reject. The original suggester of the edit has been making tons of similar edits (minor formatting changes) that usually serve very little purpose and this case are even distracting to the true point of the post. The editor and most of all the reviewers should take care not to just dumping stuff in code boxes without paying further attention to clarity.

Could we do something about these sloppy edits and sloppy reviewers, please?

Comment: Good that you edited it. Related posts: [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250092/2982225) and [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265917/2982225)

Comment: This user got **101 edit suggestions approved, and 49 edit suggestions rejected**. There is already an automatic process in place to temporarily ban such users from suggesting edits. Sooner or later it will kick in. Simply continue to reject such edits.

Comment: @AzizShaikh, thank you for letting me know. What about the reviewers? That edit should've been definitely improved or downright rejected.

Comment: Yes, that particular edit should have been rejected as _invalid_ or _too minor_. Regarding the approvers of such edits, I don't think there is any automatic process, however I have seen instances where site moderators have temporarily banned such users from reviewing.

Comment: It troubles me somewhat that the automatic solution for getting bad editors banned relies on us having good reviewers, while the reviewers aren't being moderated.

Comment: I saw a similar edit attempt the other day where quote format was used as highlight. Somebody also tried to change bracing styles again. But both looked like isolated cases, at least based on the 20 reviews/day I'm doing. I think I'll start taking notes of the names to see if there are larger scale patterns.

Comment: There are two ways that people can be banned from reviewing. Failing too many review audits, or a manual ban handed out by a moderator.

Comment: What I like to do in these cases is accept those edits, but uncheck the "helpful" button. Then you can go back and do the edit properly without having to race against robo-reviewers, and the bad editor doesn't get his/her rep.

Comment: See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137755/reject-an-already-approved-suggested-edit-when-rolling-it-back and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221832/moderators-should-be-able-to-manually-ban-users-from-suggesting-edits.

Comment: @kviiri Well, the reviewers are regularly audited automatically.  However, the audits are generated from previous reviews, so it's like a spiral of bad...

Comment: @Izkata: The audits in the edit review queue are all just fake edits with random words inserted in random places. They are completely obvious. They stand out before you even start reading, just based on the pattern in the diff. This is different from audits in other review queues, where the audit examples come from real data.

Comment: @user3580294 Of course, if you do that enough, someone may call you out in a meta post like this one ;) Something is clearly wrong when you have to accept bad edits just to defeat robo reviewers.

Comment: Related: [1](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255478/2371861) [2](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251333/2371861)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Forgive me if I didn't pick up on sarcasm if present, but if you improve the edit without saying it was helpful isn't the suggested edit marked as rejected? But otherwise, yes, the edit system is not functioning ideally, if it isn't downright broken, and something should be done about it sooner rather than later.

Comment: Since I am one of the approver, _shame on me_. As we all agree, this edit is not adequate.